# Visual Studio is deleting my environment variable additions to docker.compose.vs.debug.g.yml

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

First of all I am running this locally in Visual Studio 2019 so that is the environment I am currently trying to find my issues in right now.  It's .NETCORE 3.1 and going to Linux.

I have inherited a project which I need to debug locally but is going to be pushed up to ECS on AWS most of the CI/CD has been setup around this container now and I feel its limiting my ability to debug its issues but that is what I was handed so here I am chatting with you folks.

Currently the app runs fine when outside a container and able to use my dev environment credentials.

The issues seem to stack up when I try to locally debug the container in docker-compose and the docker therefore no longer has access to the AWS Credentials being it is its own little container.

My original nefarious plan was just to review my output and then correct the **docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml** it is using to run and shove my secret keys in there while debugging why the AWS ECS containers are exit code 139'ing on AWS.

The issue is there are a lot of cogs spinning around this now it seems and just doing a simple **"docker run -e awssecretkey=YOUWISHBOI ."** is all but impossible.

**NOTE: Please dont get hung up on any errors below this is just to demonstrate where I want to push in my environment variables. I have renamed the programs carelessly to keep the innocent anonymous.**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  pickle.application:
    image: pickle:dev
    container_name: pickle.Application
    build:
      target: base
      labels:
        com.microsoft.created-by: "visual-studio"
        com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: "pickle.Application"
    environment:
      - NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages
      **- HOW_DO_I=KEEP_SOMETHING_HERE**
    volumes:
      - C:\mq-tech\pickle-system\pickle\pickle\src\pickle.Application:/app
      - C:\Users\Carter-PC\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw
      - C:\Users\Carter-PC\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
      - C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.program: "dotnet"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.arguments: " --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/packages --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  \"/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/pickleApplication.dll\""
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.workingdirectory: "/app"
      com.microsoft.visualstudio.debuggee.killprogram: "/bin/sh -c \"if PID=$$(pidof dotnet); then kill $$PID; fi\""
    tty: true
```

So I suppose my question is whats the proper way with docker-compose debugging to put my AWS environment variables where it will debug and have them?

I imagine I could be coming at this the entirely wrong way, have mercy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this answer is a bit late, but someone still might find it useful.

You can create a `docker-compose.vs.debug.yml` file, which will be provided by VS as the last one when running docker-compose command (so it won't get overwritten).

It can look something like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  pickle.application:
    environment:
      - HOW_DO_I=KEEP_SOMETHING_HERE
```

The same rule applies to the `docker-compose.vs.release.yml` file, but in release mode.

Documentation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019#docker-compose-file-labels

Comment: Awesome thanks, Yes I am far beyond ever needing this for a while but perhaps it will come in handy again one day.   Thanks!